# Items in picker from a list - Xamarin Code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am stuck on how to show items from a list in a picker.

I can use a for loop and add the items to the Picker, is there any other way ? I have to also use bound values from the list.  All I get right now is the type and not the ID or Category name i need.

Image of what I see...
[image: image of what i see...]

```
        private async void GetCategories(string url)
    {
        //get json as a string
        var result = await _clientHttp.GetStringAsync(url);


        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CategoryList>>(result);

        List<CategoryList> tempList = new List<CategoryList>();
        foreach (var items in json)
        {

          tempList.Add(new CategoryList{CatId = items.CatId,category = items.category});

        }
        ;

        PickerCategory.ItemsSource =  tempList;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override your `CategoryList.ToString()` method  to display the appropriate values:

```
class CategoryList{

    public string category {get;set;}

    public override string ToString(){
         return category;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. added the code to the class, how do i now access the override to get the category.

Comment: you can also use `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"` to specify which property to display

Comment: @rsb123 You don't have to. When the item displays in the `Picker`, what will be displayed depends on the object's `ToString` method, and the default not-overridden one returns the class type name. By implementing that override you should automatically be able to see the `category` property value in the picker list.

Comment: it works great.. but if i only return the category how can i access the Id. I will need that to use that to show the currently selected Category ..  public class CategoryList
    {
        public string CatId { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return category;
        }

Comment: return category + " " + id;